# Converting a query to prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

been trying at this for a couple of hours with non luck.

We have this query

```
$commercial_name = strip_tags($_POST['commercial_beer']);    
$q = "SELECT bb_comm_id FROM bb_commercial WHERE bb_comm_name = '" . $commercial_name . "'";    
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.
$row = @mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$comm_id = $row['bb_comm_id'];
```

Which works fine.  I am trying to use prepared statements and came up with this

```
$commercial_name = strip_tags($_POST['commercial_beer']);   
$q = "SELECT bb_comm_id FROM bb_commercial WHERE bb_comm_name = ?"; 
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $commercial_name);
$r = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$row = @mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$comm_id = $row['bb_comm_id'];
```

Which doesn't work.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: What is the problem? White page? Doesn't fetch? Doesn't execute the query?

Comment: In your parameter binding function, change the `i` to an `s`.  I am assuming that the value of `$commercial_name` is a string and you are specifying that it is an `int`.  PHP doesn't generally care too much, by MySQL is a little pickier

Comment: For best results on StackOverflow (or in anywhere you are asking for help with a problem) please describe what you expected to happen, what happened instead, and what error messages you received. If you can add any additional information about what you tried to do to fix the problem, that can be helpful as well.

Comment: Important tip: don't use `@`! Suppressing errors is exactly the wrong thing to do if something "doesn't work" and you cannot see why.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not very clear what is your problem I'll share the code I use to debug my database queries. I'll even abridge it to your code.

```
$commercial_name = strip_tags($_POST['commercial_beer']);
if($stmt=$dbc->prepare("SELECT bb_comm_id FROM bb_commercial WHERE bb_comm_name = ?")){
    if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $commercial_name)) {
        echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        foreach($row as $key => $val) {
            $x[$key] = $val;
        }
        $comm_id[] = $x;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}else{
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $dbc->errno . ") " . $dbc->error;
}
```

This code will report if error occurs on every step, and will save all the rows from the result set inside `$comm_id`.

Try it and tell me if you still have the problem.

Also I believe the character before `$commercial_name` should be `"s"` instead of `"i"` since it's a string, presumably, not a integer.

A more 'production ready' version:

```
$stmt=$dbc->prepare("SELECT bb_comm_id FROM bb_commercial WHERE bb_comm_name = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $commercial_name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        foreach($row as $key => $val) {
            $x[$key] = $val;
        }
        $comm_id[] = $x;
    }
$stmt->close();
```

Afterwards you can  fetch the rows from $comm_id, for example, the first result will be stored inside `$comm_id[0]["bb_comm_id"]`

or if you expect only 1 row as an answer:

```
$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT bb_comm_id FROM bb_commercial WHERE bb_comm_name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $commercial_name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($comm_id);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Sorry, new to PHP and forum.  I am getting the following error via email<p>An error occurred in script '/home/dowricks/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/information/beer-base.tpl' on line 158: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
<br />Date/Time: 9-11-2014 11:27:24

Comment: @PaulDowrick you get this error because your SQL statement fails to execute so the result is `false` instead of `resultset`. Try executing the same query directly inside your sql console.

Comment: I added

$commercial_name = strip_tags($_POST['commercial_beer']); 
$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT bb_comm_id FROM bb_commercial WHERE bb_comm_name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $commercial_name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($comm_id);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

and got

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in ...  on line 142

where line 142 is

$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT bb_comm_id FROM bb_commercial WHERE bb_comm_name = ?");

Many thanks

Paul

Comment: @PaulDowrick That means that the query fails to execute inside the mysql server or returns a empty result. The prepared statement is working. Can you post a example of the final query, something like `SELECT bb_comm_id FROM bb_commercial WHERE bb_comm_name = 'John';`

Comment: SELECT bb_comm_id FROM bb_commercial WHERE bb_comm_name = "Woodfordes Wherry"

Comment: @PaulDowrick can you tell me if the query executes inside phpmyadmin/terminal and the output of the command `var_dump($commercial_name);`?